# How to make 1 div in each wrap stay in right and top

Tags: css

How to make `.c` in each `.wp_list` stay in right and top, like `right:0 top: 0`?
I set position absolute but if that way `top: 0` stand `.wp` not `.wp_list`
http://jsfiddle.net/8dMrx/

```
.wp{
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 450px;
}
.wp_list{
    background-color: red;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 130px;
}
.a, .b, .c{
    background-color: gray;
}
.a{
    width: 220px;
    height: 30px;
}
.b{
    width: 220px;
    height: 100px;
}
.c{
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
}
```

html

```
<div class="wp">
    <div class="wp_list">
        <div class="a">a</div>
        <div class="b">b</div>
        <div class="c">c</div>
    </div>
    <div class="wp_list">
        <div class="a">a</div>
        <div class="b">b</div>
        <div class="c">c</div>
    </div>
    // generate from php
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:-

```
.wp_list{
    background-color: red;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 130px;
    position:relative; /*mark parent as relative*/
}

.c{
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    top:0; /*set right and top of the relative parent*/
    right:0;
    position:absolute; /*mark child as absolute*/
}
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MqPDH/)

Comment: Just to add on for a nice explanation go through this http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Comment: why if I set .a .b .c margin:10px; .a and .c still like margin-top:0

Comment: I try to set .a .b .c like margin: 10 , have space around and each .wp_list margin: 10 too, but it all looks like not leave top space

Answer (score 1):

You can position the `.c` elements aboslutely:

```
.c{
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
}
```

You'll also want to position the containers relatively, so that `.c` elements are positioned absolutely within `.wp_list` elements rather than `.wp`:

```
.wp_list{
    position:relative;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 130px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8dMrx/1/